# problems with onchange function from React + next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, next.js, onchange

my form only writes the previous value

```
let [userStateLog, userSetStateLogin]:any = useState({login: ''})

function changeLogin(event:any){
      userSetStateLogin({[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
}

<input placeholder="Login" name="login" onChange={changeLogin} className="login"/>
```

when writing a value through onchange, only the previous value is written to the state parameter

1 onchange event => event.targe.value = **1** => myState = ' '

2 onchange event => event.target.value = **12** => myState = '***1***'

3 onchange event => event.target.value = **123** => myState = '***12***'

I don't understand why myState is one step behind

How to fix it?
When sending to another component and returning a checked value. Lagging can be observed in 2 - 3 steps.
How do I fix this?

all code :

```
export default function Auth ():JSX.Element {
   let [userStateLog, userSetStateLogin]:any = useState({login: ''})
   function changeLogin(event:any){
      let login:any = document.querySelector('.login')
      userSetStateLogin({[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
      console.log(userStateLog)
   }
   return(<>
   <input placeholder="Login" name="login" onChange={changeLogin} className="login"/>
   </>)
}
```

[image]

**thanks to all! it helped me a lot!**

Comment: where is your value prop on your input? can you share the full component please

Comment: Where are you performing your `console.log()`? The `userSetStateLogin()` won't change `userStateLog` immediately once it is called.

Comment: console.log() - I use immediately after calling

Comment: @HLEBHLEB yeah, that's your issue then. `userSetStateLogin()` will eventually cause your component to re-render with the new/updated `userStateLog` value. You can see so by moving your log before you `return` your JSX from your component to log upon each render.

Comment: how then to make it update immediately?

Comment: React state updates are asynchronously processed. Log the updated state in an `useEffect` with appropriate dependency.

Comment: i used useEffect. But the problems kept repeating

Comment: If issue persists can you try creating *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue for us to inspect and live debug?